# Unable to access function arguments in Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm writing a sample application using Kotlin Coroutines. Here is a simple function I've used

```
fun calculateData(data: Person) {
    println("Calling calculateData()...")
    launch {
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          println("Obtained data is $data")
          if(person.age > 18) {
           //do some long running calculations based on 'data'
          } 
       }
       println("Some meaningful message")
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs OK. However, I don't get the data argument inside the Coroutine. Neither can I debug into withContext block. The message "Obtained data is $data" never gets displayed

Any clue on what prevents me from accessing that argument from within Coroutine?

Comment: You should have access to `data` object in a coroutine. What is this `data: <ClassA> type` ? it is not being compiled. What do you mean by `I don't get the data argument inside the Coroutine`? Can you put logs there and print `data` to console?

Comment: It is a data object of type Person, a normal entity class. I have modified the snippet to have better understanding.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `calculateData()` in the right place? is `"Some meaningful message"` displayed? Try to set logs before `launch` function and check if `calculateData()` is invoked at all

Comment: Yes, the message "Calling calculateData()..." is displayed

Comment: Could you please update the question with the code for coroutine scope you are using to launch the coroutine

Comment: Spot on! I was using a different context which was the issue. Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: Could you provide an answer to your question as well? It might help others later.